# Access violation reading location in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, memory, visual-studio-2017

I wrote a code that should get a directory to a folder and check all files in there if they have a value of other inputted file.
(for example, there is a picture and I want to check if he has the value 'abcabc' inside, in reality, I search for 500 bytes to compare not 6)
and I get the above problem when in Visual Studio 2017 I try to open the first file in the directory, just to be sure I compiled it with GCC through the command line and it works perfectly.
So, why is that? is Visual Studio compiler is different or can allocate less memory what sounds ridiculous but its the only thing I can think of(i allocated lot memory, by a lot I mean 2kb maybe, not really a lot but more than just a string).
here is the code that the exception happens:
`FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "rb");`
the file is correct, I know it because I checked in the debug mode

Comment: You probably have some [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. Have you tried catching the crash in the VS debugger to see when and where in your code it happens?

Comment: yep, it happens when I try to open the file, the function gets a string and he is correct. The biggest mystery is that sometimes visual do open the file.